# Can't suppress CA1709 in any way

Tags: .net, code-analysis, fxcop

I want to suppress CA1709: Identifiers should be cased correctly, on
`public class IDd`. For example i want to use IDd as correct word. But i can't. I tried everything at code analysis dictionary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Dictionary>
  <Words>
    <Unrecognized>
      <Word></Word>
    </Unrecognized>
    <Recognized>
      <Word>d</Word>
      <Word>IDd</Word>
    </Recognized>
        <Deprecated>
            <Term PreferredAlternate=""></Term>
        </Deprecated>
        <Compound>
            <Term CompoundAlternate="IDd">IDd</Term>
        </Compound>
    <DiscreteExceptions>
      <Term>IDd</Term>
    </DiscreteExceptions>
  </Words>
  <Acronyms>
    <CasingExceptions>
      <Acronym>IDd</Acronym>
      <Acronym>ID</Acronym>
      <Acronym>d</Acronym>
    </CasingExceptions>
  </Acronyms>
</Dictionary>
```

But nothing helps me to add this work as correct with that case. What would you advise?

Comment: Do you want it suppressed for that that one case, or for the entire solution?

Comment: Use the [SuppressMessage] attribute on the class.

Comment: I want suppress it for all solution. I can suppress it by [SuppressMessage] attribute... but is wrong way to suppress all words at all places by this attribute. For this purpose there is code analysis dictionary. But it doesn't works very well or i don't know ho to use it in such case...

Comment: OK. I was going to show you how to suppress the rule by excluding it in the ruleset, but it sounds like you still want the rule, but have it working "correctly"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the "Dd", not the full "IDd", which is what the message of the CA1709 violation should be showing.

This can be addressed quite adding "dd" to the dictionary as a recognized word if you consider to be an actual word:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dictionary>
    <Words>
        <Recognized>
            <Word>dd</Word>
        </Recognized>
    </Words>
</Dictionary>
```

or by adding it as an acronym casing exception if you do not consider it to be a word by still want to use pascal casing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dictionary>
    <Acronyms>
        <CasingExceptions>
            <Acronym>Dd</Acronym>
        </CasingExceptions>
    </Acronyms>
</Dictionary>
```

Comment: 1st example with <Recognized> words don't works...  That is confusing to me.. why i cant add IDd with respect of case to the dictionary... Neither IDd nor dd.. Second one is working but it is also not perfect every Dd will be  casing exception. But i want just only word IDd.

Comment: "IDd" exclusions won't work because the rule has a special case to ignore a leading "I" (intended for interface names, but it gets overused by the rule).  Adding "dd" to the recognized words list works just fine for me.  Which version of Visual Studio Code Analysis or FxCop are you using?

Comment: I can repro.  The recognized word approach works in VS2010, but not in VS2012.