# Can i use static analysis in VS2012 from VS2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, code-analysis

For the comparability reasons on the first stage i want to use VS2010 engine from the Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\ in the VS 2012... Is there any way to do this?

---

i was able to replace(fake) files of the code analysis  from 11 to 10.. Analysis works. But i can't see CA errors(number and discription) when they heppens

---

I have overrided CodeAnalysisPath, CodeAnalysisStaticAnalysisDirectory and CodeAnalysisTargets  to 10.0 version and I founded that  VS 2012 invokes FxCopCmd.exe with /outputCulture:1049 and VS 2010 with /outputCulture:1033 all other parametrs are the same. So that is the reason. But i can't find outputCulture pparametr in the FxCopCmd help... that is VSLANG! (visual studio language)...It seems that problem was solved by overriding only CodeAnalysisPath and using the same language version of VS. Because before i had English VS 2010 and Russian VS 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get this working simply by pointing to the VS 2010 FxCop folder from within your VS 2012 project (e.g.: .csproj or .vbproj):

```
<CodeAnalysisPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\</CodeAnalysisPath>
```

N.B.: This path does not necessarily have to be in Program Files.  It will work equally well when pointing to a source-controlled relative path, which is handy if you are already managing your tool dependencies in your source tree.

Comment: I  read about that... and tried, but it doesn't works. In VS2010 all works fine but in VS2012 i got many errors. Except CodeAnalysisPath there are CodeAnalysisStaticAnalysisDirectory and CodeAnalysisTargets that are differs and cause different behavior... Now i think  i need to setup CodeAnalysisPath, CodeAnalysisStaticAnalysisDirectory and customize CodeAnalysisTargets because i can't override target to 10.0 because visual studio 2012 don't undestand error messages from old target and Code Analysis  rules are used in different way..

Comment: That's rather odd.  I'm seeing no problems in VS2012 after switching CodeAnalysisPath to point at the VS2010 code analysis folder.  What are the "many errors" you are seeing?

Comment: A lot of CA1709 like from my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467327/cant-suppress-ca1709-in-any-way where we can see that words analysis and it suppression are differs . Also others like avoid excessive coupling. Maybe you are just lucky that you don't have errors )

Comment: You try that this approach don't work just override <CodeAnalysisPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\</CodeAnalysisPath> in the project file with the sample from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467327/cant-suppress-ca1709-in-any-way and you will see that this don't helps.

Comment: It was solved by installing English VS2012 ( before i have Rushian2012 and English 2010)